# how to add a mean column for the groupby movieID?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a df like below

```
    userId      movieId rating  
0   1       31          2.0 
1   2       10          4.0 
2   2       17          5.0 
3   2       39          5.0 
4   2       47          4.0 
5   3       31          3.0
6   3       10          2.0
```

I need to add two column, one is `mean` for each movie, the other is `diff` which is the difference between rating and mean.

Please note that `movieId` can be repeated because different users may rate the same movie. Here row 0 and 5 is for `movieId` 31, row 1 and 6 is for `movieId` 10

```
    userId  movieId rating  mean   diff  
0     1   31      2.0      2.5       -0.5
1     2   10      4.0      3         1
2     2   17      5.0      5         0
3     2   39      5.0      5         0
4     2   47      4.0      4         0
5     3   31      3.0      2.5       0.5
6     3   10      2.0      3         -1
```

here is some of my code which calculates the mean

```
df = df.groupby('movieId')['rating'].agg(['count','mean']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` to keep the same number of rows when calculating mean with `groupby`. Calculating the difference is straightforward from that:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('movieId')['rating'].transform('mean')
df['diff'] = df['rating'] - df['mean']
```

Comment: It shows ''SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mean'

Comment: That seems strange. Are you executing the code as I posted exactly? And is `df` the same dataframe that you provided in your post?

Comment: your code is right. appreciated. But my real business request here is to have two columns named 'rating_mean' and 'rating_adjusted'.............here is my updated code.............full_ratings['rating_mean'] = full_ratings.groupby('movieId')['rating'].transform('rating_mean')
full_ratings['rating_adjusted'] = full_ratings['rating'] - full_ratings['rating_mean']

Comment: oh, I know why...I should still keep transform('mean')